# How to figure out why app is crashing when trying to access SystemPreferences data

Tags: java, android, system-preferences

I am trying to maintain a userID and username throughout my app. I created a class called Session that places and receives data to SharedPreferences and setting it works just fine. The problem I am getting is when I go to retrieve it in another activity.

The Session Class Constructor

```
 public Session(Context cntx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
    }
```

The Session Class method to add a userID and the method to retrieve it

```
 public void setUserID(int userID) {
        prefs.edit().putInt("userID", userID).apply();
    }

public int getID() {
        int userID;

        return userID = prefs.getInt("userID",0);

    }
```

Setting the ID on login

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        builder.setTitle("Server Response");
                        builder.setMessage("Response :"+response);

                        session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
                        int responseInt = Integer.parseInt(response.trim());
                        session.setUserID(responseInt);

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, navActivity.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                        finish();
```

Trying to retrieve that ID and putting into an editText

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_jars);
        session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
        userID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userID);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyJars.this);
        userID.setText(session.getID());
```

I wanted to be able to pull that data and send it to my server where I can run my PHP scripts as I have with other activities but this isn't cooperating.

Comment: "this isn't cooperating." - What happens? Is there a crash? Do you have a LogCat stacktrace?

Comment: The app crashes. I can add the logcat output.

Comment: Yes - please update your question to include the stacktrace (although Forpas may be onto something with their answer)

Comment: It isn't crashing anymore, Forpas's answer worked. Should I still add the old LogCat for future users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
userID.setText(session.getID());
```

`session.getID()` is an integer and it is interpreted as an integer resource id and not as the string text that you want to set in `userID`.
Change to this:

```
userID.setText("" + session.getID());
```

or

```
userID.setText(String.valueOf(session.getID()));
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding ignorant does this mean that only string values can be added to an edit text?

Comment: Anything that can be converted to string. So with `String.valueOf(..)` you can convert a number to string.

Comment: Since this worked you may consider accepting the answer

Comment: I thought I did I'm sorry.

Comment: Fine, no worries.